# How to change username/userid in custom webchat implementation bot framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

I need to populate the username dynamically in custom webchat control. I know that webchat renders the username present in the script, but how do I change that? I have even tried to send activity with the different username from server side using .NET SDK but still couldn't achieve.

[Custom Web Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgYOh.png)

```
<script>

            var user = {
                id: 'user-id',
                name: 'user name'
            };

            var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                token: '[directlinesecret]',
                user: user
            });

            BotChat.App({
                user: user,
                botConnection: botConnection,
                bot: { id: 'bot-id', name: 'bot name' },
                resize: 'detect'
            }, document.getElementById("bot"));

            botConnection
                .postActivity({
                    from: user,
                    name: 'requestWelcomeDialog',
                    type: 'event',
                    value: ''
                })
                .subscribe(function (id) {
                    console.log('"trigger requestWelcomeDialog" sent');
                });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to populate the username dynamically in custom webchat control.

I assume that you’d like to embed Web Chat to your website and dynamically specify `user: { id: user_id, name: user_name }` based on the current user (login user), you can try to retain user information in a cookie when the user login your website, and then you can retrieve information of the current user from cookie and initiate web chat.

*Example:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wc-chatview-panel {
            width: 350px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initiatewebchat()">
   <div id="chat"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function initiatewebchat() {

        var botuser = getCookie("botuser");

        if (botuser!=null) {
            var userinfo = JSON.parse(botuser);

            var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
                secret: '{directline_secret_here}',
            });

            var user = {
                id: userinfo.user_id,
                name: userinfo.user_name
            };

            var bot = {
                id: 'fehanbasicbot',
                name: 'botname'
            };

            BotChat.App({
                botConnection: botConnection,
                user: user,
                bot: bot,
            }, document.getElementById('chat'));

        } else {
            alert("do not find user identity for web chat! please login to our website.");
        }
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

*Test result:*

[image]

***Note:***

In above test sample, I retain `"{"user_id":"0001","user_name":"user1"}"` in cookie.

[image]

Comment: Hi Fei Han, Thanks for quick input. In my case user doesn't login, but yes we are storing state in Azure Table Storage where in user name is present(bot asks user about name previously before ordering an item). I am able to get name from azure table storage using state management in C# SDK , but unable to figure out how to send that in javascript. Sorry, as I am new i don't know if I am missing something here.

Comment: If possible, you can prompt the user to input user name by using [prompt() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) when page loads, and then you can pass the user name of current name to initiate web chat.

Comment: Sure thanks Fei Han, but looking for retrieving username from azure table storage.